# How do I send a Line Model control command to a Zebra printer?

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers, epl

I have the following code, which I send after putting the printer in line mode, but it just prints the '51' after swallowing the `[ESC]A`

The command to change font is `[ESC]A51`

```
var hexValue = "1B"; // ESC char in HEX
var asciiValue = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexValue, 16));
var stringVal = new string(new char[] { asciiValue });
stringVal = stringVal + "A51"; // Smaller Font

data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringVal + NewLine);

connection.Write(data);
```

Comment: What type of object is `connection`?

Comment: the `hexValue` is not correct write `hexValue = 0x1b;`?

Answer (score 0):

Need some correct codes to normalize the output to printer.

```
var stringVal = new string(new char[] { System.Convert.ToChar(0x1b) /* ESC */, 
                                        'A', 
                                        System.Convert.ToChar(51) });
data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stringVal + NewLine);

connection.Write(data);
```

**EDIT**

In this case `A51` need attention. If `51` is string, using `'5', '1'`, or a char, using `System.Convert.ToChar(51)`, the command is different way to pass.